# ImageMagick Pdf to JPG bad quality

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I am not able to get good color quality from using ImageMagick to convert PDF to images.

```
 MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
        settings.Verbose = true;
        settings.Density = new Density(600, 600);

        MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection();
        images.Read("C:\\" + Path.GetFileName(fileUrl));
        List <string> files = new List<string>();
        for (var x = 0; x < images.Count; x++)
        {
            images[x].Quality = 100;
            images[x].BitDepth(24);
            images[x].Contrast(true);
            images[x].Resize(3675, 2400);
            images[x].Write("C:\\websites\\FlyerEditor2\\FlyerEditor\\src\\assets\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileUrl) + "-" + (x + 1) + ".jpeg");
            files.Add("assets/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileUrl) + "-" + (x + 1) + ".jpeg");
        }
```

[cropped screenshot from pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VNE5.jpg)

[jpg from pdf using imageMagick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dylo7.jpg)

Comment: Please show input and output image examples, so we can see what you mean by not good color quality. Try setting the quality and bit depth after contrast and resize. Try your code on one single image. Does that fail? Try the equivalent command line code? Does that fail? If so, then show that command line.

Comment: Ok, maybe I messed up I provided links above to the images

Comment: I am not sure how to display images automatically

Comment: @fmw42 I guess a rep of 10 is required to embed images

Comment: If you are starting with a PDF, you should post a link to that PDF and not a screen shot, in order to be able to test with your original PDF. Also ImageMagick uses Ghostscript to process PDF files. Is your Ghostscript up to date? What is your version of ImageMagick and Ghostscript?

Comment: Post your original PDF so we can see what colorspace it uses and any other issues.

Comment: We need to be able to access your actual PDF, not a screen snap.

Comment: You could simply extract the image from the PDF using pdf2image tool.

Answer (score 1):

if use python3, you can try use wand.

in terminal：

```
brew install imagemagick@6
pip install wand
```

in python:

```
from wand.image import Image
pdf_file = '.../example/a.pdf'

def convert_pdf_to_jpg(file_name, pic_file, resolution=120):
    with Image(filename=file_name, resolution=resolution) as img:
        print('pages = ', len(img.sequence))
        with img.convert('jpeg') as converted:
            converted.save(filename=pic_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found major differences in imagemagick's convert handling of colorspace between Linux and Windows.

Using commands

```bash
convert -density 300 -colorspace RGB my.pdf my.jpg
convert -density 300 -colorspace sRGB my.pdf my.jpg
```

On Linux, both `-colorspace sRGB` and `-colorspace RGB` generated images where contrast and palette were a major diversion from the original, contrast was increased and colors were a far match from the original.

On Windows, both `-colorspace sRGB` and `-colorspace RGB` were acceptable if not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue has nothing to do with imageMagick. It is a simple issue with color pallets. Converting a pdf to a jpeg by default uses cmyk, while the web standard is RGB

Comment: That is not necessarily true for ImageMagick unless the PDF is already CMYK. ImageMagick will keep the colorspace unless requested to change it when converting PDF to JPG. So the OP should add the equivalent of -colorspace sRGB (or RGB for very old Imagemaick versions) before reading the PDF.